# Can I build an ActionLink through a Helper class? How?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a helper class to build my hyperlink. The markup looks like this:

```
<a href='/controller/action?id=val'></a>
```

This is the same markup that the `Html.ActionLink()` produces. However, if I use the `Html.ActionLink()`, the id is accepted as a parameter in the method inside the controller. If I just generate the `a` tag in a string like the above I get the error below when I try to define the method with an id parameter:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' 
of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' 
...

To make a parameter optional its type should be either a reference    
type or a Nullable type.
Parameter name: parameters
```

1. Is there a way to use `Html.ActionLink()` in my helper class?
2. Why is there a difference between the two techniques?

Here's my controller action:

```
public ActionResult AssignmentAdd(int id)
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code of your html helper call, the controller action method signature and the routes setup in global.asax because all three are related. Also the error message/exception you are getting.

Comment: Can we see your controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a routing problem. I guess your controller action has to be modified to accept a nullable integer for the id parameter:

```
public ActionResult Action(int? id) 
{ }
```

Also if you followed the default routing table as generated by the template the correct link for this action should be:

```
<a href="/controller/action/val"></a>
```

And the helper to generate it:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("link text", "action", new { id = "val" }) %>
```

Comment: Your example above re: ActionLink works for me too, I was just wondering if I can put that or something like that in my helper class (which is just a plain partial class)?

Comment: Your helper class should really be a static class that contains HtmlHelper extension methods. In which case, yes you could call the ActionLink method in your helper class because you're working with the HtmlHelper! :-)